# How to prevent mongoose from creating collections?

Tags: mongoose

I have a defined two schemas in my application: schema A which is the "main" document and schema B which is embedded in document generated from schema A. Now, schema B has the `_id` property set, and everything works fine. However when I access any document a new empty collection is created for schema B type objects, since mongoose thinks that schema B objects has their own collection (while it's not).
Is there a way to tell mongoose not to create this collection? I tried setting the `{_id: false}` or `{strict: false}` options on the schema B definition, but that didn't worked

This is the schema B definition

```
const SchemaBDefinition = new Schema(
  {
    position: Number,
    title: String,
    ...
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const SchemaBModel = db.model("SchemaB", SchemaBDefinition );

exports.model = SchemaBModel;
```

And this is how I use it in Schema A

```
const { model: SchemaBModel } = require("./schemaB");

const SchemaADefinition = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    refs: [SchemaBModel],
    ...
  }
);
```

Comment: can you add code for your schemas to the question?

Comment: Sure, edited just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to generate a collection for SchemaB, you shouldn't  create a model for schemaB here `const SchemaBModel = db.model("SchemaB", SchemaBDefinition );`

I think what you are trying to do is embedding SchemaB inside SchemaA.

If so you do simply like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SchemaBDefinition = new Schema(
  {
    position: Number,
    title: String
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const SchemaADefinition = new Schema({
  name: String,
  refs: [SchemaBDefinition]
});

const SchemaAModel = mongoose.model("ModelA", SchemaADefinition);

exports.model = SchemaAModel;
```